# import yahoo finance interactive chart

Tags: charts, yahoo, finance

it seems yahoo has moved largechart.swf so my code is not working anymore

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
id="yfi_chart_swf" 
data="http://l.yimg.com/bm/lib/fi/common/p/d/static/swf/2.0.253765/2.0.0/it-IT/largechart.swf" 
width="600" height="516" style="visibility: visible; height: 500px;">
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
<param name="wmode" value="opaque">
<param name="flashvars" value="sigDevEnabled=false&amp;changeSymbolEnabled=false&amp;state=symbol=<? echo $data_code;?>;range=1d;compare=;indicator=mfi%2Bvolume;charttype=area;crosshair=on;ohlcvalues=0;logscale=off;source=undefined;">
</object>
```

do you have any suggestion in how to solve the problem... i know ther's the possibility to import a static image but i would like to keep show an interactive chart...
thanks